# How to unit test a time related method?

Tags: java, junit

Suppose we have this interface:

```
interface CallChecker {
    boolean canCall(String ipAddress, Object method);
}
```

And we limit 10 calls per second from one IP for each method, i.e. if a method is called more than 10 times in one second, `CallChecker::canCall(ip, method)` should return false.

How do we unit test this function?

Side question: is there a better way to define `method` instead of `Object` type?

Comment: Is that 1 second is clock accurate ,meaning every clock second is a separate frame for 10 requests max, or do 1 second frame starts at the instant of the first request beeing made?

Comment: @Antoniossss that's a good question. I would say the latter - start 1 second frame from the first request.

Comment: I was just curious as at the end it is irrelevant. Implementation will either look as clock frame or will compare to the "oldest" request. In testing context, the same approach should work for both cases I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you have to register the timestamp of individual requests to see of they are > 1 and spans for less  than 1 second.

In runtime, you will use eg system clock, `Instant.now()` or whatever. In unit tests, you will set those timestamps manually. Something like (conceptual only):

```
t0=Instant.now();
for(int i=1;i++;i<=10){
  yourService.handleRequest(request,t0.plusMilis(i*10));
  assertThat(yourSrvice.canMakeRequest).isTrue();
}
  yourService.handleRequest(request,t0.plusMilis(300));
  assertThat(yourSrvice.canMakeRequest).isFalse();
```

Now you are free to simulate timelapse by setting request timestamps at will. That is just one of possibilities.

Comment: I was thinking that `Instant.now()` should be wrapped, and that Wrapper injected into the implementation.  Then for a unit test, the Wrapper can be mocked, and have it return whatever `Instant` is needed for the test case.

Comment: Ye, you can use a `ClockService` that will provide you an `Instant`  of request, and you can provide mocked impl of it instead of real clock based impl . This is exactly the same idea.

Comment: If you are trying to alter behavior of `Instant`, pass one of the artificial [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) objects returned by the various static methods on `Clock`.